# How do I change the default message digest in openssl 1.1.0

Tags: ssh, password, encryption, ssl

**EDIT:**
I have a file that was encrypted with openssl 1.0.1g. When it was encrypted, the `default_md` was md5. How can I set openssl 1.1.0 to use `default_md` to md5 when executing commands in user mode?

using `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`:

There is a `default_md` parameter under the `[ CA_default ]` section, and I don't want to modify that. I found a stackexchange post where someone suggested adding `default_md = md5` under the `[ req ]` section, but that hasn't worked. Is there another section that I have to add the config to to use md5 Message Digest in user mode?

**TL;DR:** How do I change the default message digest to MD5 in openssl 1.1.0? There is a parameter for it: `default_md`, but seems to be ignored when set.

---

---

---

**Original Question:**
I have a proprietary encryption tool that was compiled on Ubuntu 14 using OpenSSL 1.0.1g that no longer works on Ubuntu 18. Seeing as I can't just recompile this proprietary tool, I need to enabled whatever Ubuntu 14 (openssl 1.0.1g) was using in Ubuntu 18 (openssl 1.1.0g). It has something to do with the digest envelop, which has changed from MD5 to SHA256.

I found an option in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf under the [ req ] section called default_md. I set the value to

```
 default_md = md5
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I also added a wrapper script to my path that passes in the `-md5` parameter to openssl, but the digest still isn't recognized.

Comment: More research suggests that it's a problem with openssl 1.1.0 not being backward compatible to 1.0.1.

Comment: I tried to change default_md to "md5" in my /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf file, but that didn't do anything.